# AFNetworking Lexical or preprocessor issue Expected ':'

Tags: afnetworking-2

I downloaded the latest AFNetworking framework 2.5 and tried out the example project. However, my build has failed with the following error in AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h, AFURLConnectionOperation.h, AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h.

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Expected ':'

Can anyone help why this error occurs? How to resolve it? I am using xcode 5.1.1 with IOS 7.0 sdk.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: have you solved it or not? if yes then tell us kindly

Answer (score 0):

For AFNetworking version greater than 2.0 minimum iOS target is iOS 6 and minimum OS X target is OX X 10.8. so just update to the minimum requirement and you would be able to resolve the error as it was in my case.

For requirement of AFNetworking just go through this link :
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#requirements